# How to fix google colab cutting of plots of confusion matrices

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to create a confusion matrix on google colab but once I plot it and try to save it the top and the bottom of the plot get cut off. Is there any way to fix this?

```
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sn
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from google.colab import files
array =  [[1, 0, 0], 
       [0, 1, 0.0101], 
      [0, 0, 0.9898]]
df_cm = pd.DataFrame(array, index = ["REM", "Wake", "NREM"],
              columns = ["REM", "Wake", "NREM"],)
plt.figure(figsize = (10,7))
sn.heatmap(df_cm, annot=True, cmap="YlGnBu", linewidths=0.5)
plt.savefig("Fid.pdf", bbox_inches='tight')
files.download("Fid.pdf")
```

Here is the result I'm getting.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Un4aN.jpg

Comment: I ran your code and it works perfectly fine for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reverting back to matplotlib 3.1.0

```
!pip install matplotlib==3.1.0
```

Or you can use the pre-release version (3.2.0rc)

```
!pip install --pre -U matplotlib
```