# Confusion matrix in Google colab is cutted off

Tags: python, visualization, google-colaboratory, confusion-matrix

I tried to visualize my Confusion matrix by the following code:

```
from mlxtend.plotting import plot_confusion_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sklearn as skplt
import scikitplot as skplt
skplt.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix(y_val, autokeras_predictions, figsize = (5, 5), title= 'My confusionmatrix' )
plt.figure(figsize = (10,7))
```

But it cuts off my confusion matrix above and below. (See picture) [image]

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix google colab cutting of plots of confusion matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58791437/how-to-fix-google-colab-cutting-of-plots-of-confusion-matrices)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.

I'm using `Anaconda` on Windows.

For me, the following resolved the problem:

```
from mlxtend.plotting import plot_confusion_matrix
...
multiclass = confusion_matrix(test_y, predictions)
class_names = ['16QAM', '32QAM', '64QAM', 'BPSK', 'QPSK', '8PSK']

fig, ax = plot_confusion_matrix(conf_mat=multiclass, colorbar=True,
show_absolute=False, show_normed=True, class_names=class_names)
-->ax.margins(2,2) #just change the values til adjust to your screen.
plt.show()
```

[image: My figure after adding the commented line]